# What does JsonResponse<A> and JsonResponse<String> mean in Java?

Tags: java, oop

```
public class JsonResponse<A> {
  public boolean success;
  public String message;
  public A data;


  public JsonResponse() {
  }

  public JsonResponse(boolean success, String message, A obj) {
    this.success = success;
    this.message = message;
    this.data = obj;
  }
```

What does this mean in Java?

```
 public class  JsonResponse<A> 
 new  JsonResponse<String>(false,"two","three");
```

Can someone please explain? How does this work in Java or OOP?

Comment: Is `new JsonResponse("one","two","three");` part of the code?

Comment: See the [Oracle generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Also, your code is likely to be `new  JsonResponse<String>(false,"two","three");`. I.e. the first parameter should be boolean.

Comment: both are separate one is declaring a class and other one is calling that class

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. To explain this thoroughly, we'd need to give you an overview of **Java generics**. It's a big topic, so you are best to read the link I posted in my first comment and consider another question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class JsonResponse<A>
```

declares `JsonResponse` as a class with one *type parameter*, which is called `A` inside the class.

When you use `JsonResponse<String>`, that means "`JsonResponse` with the type parameter set to `String`".

If you've ever used collections, they use this system a lot - as in `List<String>` or `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Addition of `Generics` terminology in your answer would be better !